# Repair question on wheel vibration

Tags: honda

I use a honda city 2008 but my issue is when at 80km/h, i car start to vibrate, and when i apply break it vibrate as well in 80Km/h. But if am under 70km/hr it dose not vibrate. Kindly shred light.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have a wheel that is out of balance. Sometimes, the balancing weights fall off. Visually inspect all your wheels and make sure you can see the balancing weight on all of them. They look like a little tab between the metal wheel and the rubber tire and usually have a number embossed on them. All wheel need one, if one's missing, there's your problem.

Comment: A 2008 Honda (although I'm not familiar with a *City*) may only have adhesive weights mounted on the inside of the rim, which will be difficult to  acertain whether one or more groups are missing.  Although pictures I googled clearly show the old-school tabbed weights you describe.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_City#/media/File:2014_Honda_City_(GM6_MY14)_VTi_sedan_(2015-07-15)_01.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It is always worth to spend a little money on wheel balancing and tracking. It saves money on tires, fuel consumption, chassis components..